# Export Distortion Node for Nuke or Natron?

Tags: export, compositing-nodes, tracking

Just start playing with Blender tracking recently, and everything seems to be pretty good. Except,I couldn't find a good way to export distortion data to Nuke or Natron. I used to use PFTrack and export their own distortion data,and read it into nuke with plugin. I was wondering if Blender can do the same thing? How's everybody deal with this? STMap? or Render 3D scene with distortion?

Best,

Han

Comment: answering my own question.
I couldn't find any existed solution, so I looked into Blender source code last weekend. The undistort formula is starting at line 66, both polynomial and divison, in  blender-2.78c\intern\libmv\libmv\simple_pipeline\distortion_models.h
Seems pretty straight forward formula, going to take that to Nuke blink script.

Comment: Please don't mark the title of the question as "solved". Write an answer to your own question instead and mark it as accepted. Otherwise the system still sees this post as unanswered. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The undistort formula is starting at line 66, both polynomial and divison, in blender-2.78c\intern\libmv\libmv\simple_pipeline\distortion_‌​models.h Seems pretty straight forward formula, can be implied to Nuke using Blink script, or to Natron using Shadertoy.

Comment: Did it work? Started a bounty...